# COCOS JS - Set the Label Text

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

Does anyone know how to update the text of a label on the Cocos 2D-x? I created a label on the cocos studio, now I'm trying to acess and change its content through my code.

I'm looking for a concrete line of code in JavaScript but I only found answers in C++ :(

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Let's assume you have a similar line of code to create the Label somewhere in your project (this code may be generated by cocos studio for you):

```
var label = cc.LabelTTF.create("Label text","Arial","18",cc.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
```

Now, somewhere in your code you want to modify it's value. Here's the code fore it:

```
label.setString("new text");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
properties: {
        label_captcha: {
            default: null,
            type: cc.Label
        },
    },
onLoad: function () {
   this.label_captcha.string = "test"
},
```

The tutorial is at [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l77cJj2k9SQ).